# Maven-assembly-plugin: add multiple files of multiple directories to one output directory

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Anyone an idea of how to add multiple files of multiple directories to one output directory without sub-directories using the maven assembly plugin.

Imagine following structure:

```
prjdir
   |-dir1
      |-target
         |-file1
   |-dir2
      |-target
         |-file2
   ...
   |-dirN
      |-target
         |-fileN
```

I can use a fileSet to add the files ie.:

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>../prjdir</directory>
  <outputDirectory>myoutput</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>*/target/file*</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

Which then creates the myoutput directory like:

```
myoutput
   |-dir1
      |-target
         |-file1
   |-dir2
      |-target
         |-file2
   ...
   |-dirN
      |-target
         |-fileN
```

But what the hell I should do if I want only the files on myoutput without the directory structure of the source...

```
myoutput
   |-file1
   |-file2
   ...
   |-fileN
```

This is only an simplified example, which means I need to do it a generic way.

Can't use `<files><file>` and also can't list every file explicitly, as they are generated dynamically without knowing the name beforehand ...

Thanks in advance for you support ...

Cheers m_n

Comment: Can you describe more in detail which kind of files you need to collect from the target directories?

Comment: briefly spoken, those are files generated by the build process of the sub-projects from dir1 to dirN ...

Comment: By which ? What kind of process ? Plugins? Please be more specific...

Comment: dir1 - dirN are maven projects which are bundled by a parent and generate statisical data by a plugin and writes them to the target dir.ectories .. But why is that relevant to the question on how to collect the files by a fileset and get rid of the directory structure to put them flat to a specific directory on assembling to a package by assembly-plugin ?